# Check table columns reached max length

Tags: sql, netezza

Just wondering whether there is a way to check columns of a table reached thire maximum length.

With following I was able to get the length of the table column

```
SELECT MAX(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) AS LEN, COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name IN ('TableA')
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME 
ORDER BY LEN DESC
```

And then I wanted to check whether those column reached its MAX length or not with data

Below gives the max length a column

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(Col1))
FROM TableA
```

As it is not possible to use aggregate functions in `WHERE` clause, how it is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Use having clause for using aggregate function with a cond.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join` to bring the data together:

```
SELECT MaxLen, ActualLen
FROM (SELECT MAX(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) AS MaxLen, COLUMN_NAME
      FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_name IN ('TableA') AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL1'
     ) m CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(Col1)) as ActualLen
      FROM TableA
     ) c;
```

I'm not sure what you actually want returned.  If you want the rows with the maximum value:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where length(col1) = (SELECT MAX(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) AS MaxLen
                      FROM information_schema.columns
                      WHERE table_name IN ('TableA') AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL1'
                     );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The solution can apply just for one column.
I was after doing this for all the column in the table. Is that possible?

Comment: @MPH . . . That sounds like a different question.  This question definitely uses "column" in the singular.

Comment: It's a typo, I specified "columns" in the body. Sorry about that. Updating the subject