# How to find all tables whose integer columns have reached max values?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

My primary key is an integer.
I get the error #1062 - Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'PRIMARY' on next insert.

Reason: Obviously maximum value is reached.

Is there any way i can find all tables whose integer columns have reached max values or close to reaching max values to avoid such errors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check table columns reached max length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672731/check-table-columns-reached-max-length)

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT 
      id, IF(max(id)<4294967295, 'true', 'false') as insert_flag
FROM Table
```

> **Note:** I have checked in above query, whether max id's value is less
>   then Int Range (*4294967295*). Query returns true and false in
>   insert_flag column. You can check this in your code before insertion.

Comment: i am looking to scan all tables in db

Comment: You can scan all tables with this query one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If you were talking about `id` as some kind of `AUTO_INCREMENT` field, then you can get this information for all tables with `show table status` (please use `help show table status` for more details).

e.g.

```
mysql> show table status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: test_table
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 65536
      Data_free: 0
 Auto_increment: 2
    Create_time: 2014-11-07 13:17:16
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: latin1_swedish_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to check all the auto-increment columns to see how close they are to their maximum:

```
SELECT c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME, 
(@max_auto_increment_size := CASE
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'tinyint% unsigned' THEN 255
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'tinyint%' THEN 127
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'smallint% unsigned' THEN 65535
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'smallint%' THEN 32767
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'mediumint% unsigned' THEN 16777215
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'mediumint%' THEN 8388607
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'int% unsigned' THEN 4294967295
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'int%' THEN 2147483647
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'bigint% unsigned' THEN 18446744073709551615
    WHEN c.COLUMN_TYPE like 'bigint%' THEN 9223372036854775807
    ELSE 127
END) AS MAX_AUTO_INCREMENT_SIZE,
ROUND(@max_auto_increment_size - t.AUTO_INCREMENT) AS Headroom,
(CASE
    WHEN ROUND(@max_auto_increment_size - t.AUTO_INCREMENT) < 1000 THEN 'CRITICAL'
    WHEN ROUND(@max_auto_increment_size - t.AUTO_INCREMENT) < 10000 THEN 'LOW'
    ELSE 'OK'
END) AS Remark
FROM information_schema.columns c
JOIN tables t ON (t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA AND t.TABLE_NAME = c.TABLE_NAME)
WHERE c.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')
AND c.EXTRA = 'auto_increment'
ORDER BY c.TABLE_SCHEMA, c.TABLE_NAME, c.COLUMN_NAME;
```